# Problem with registering xtype

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am trying to create factory functions as per [factory-functions-in-ext-extensions](http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/factory-functions-in-ext-extensions/),
below is my code

```
Ext.ns('MyApp');

MyApp.SubmitButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Button, {
     text:'Submit'
    ,iconCls:'icon-disk'
    ,initComponent:function() {
        MyApp.SubmitButton.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    } // eo function initComponent
}); // eo extend



var btn = new MyApp.SubmitButton();
Ext.reg('submitbutton1',btn);//this is not working

Ext.reg('submitbutton', MyApp.SubmitButton );//this works

var win1;
if(!win1) {
        win1 = new Ext.Window({
            title       : 'title',
            closeAction : 'hide',
            autoHeight  : true,
            autoWidth   : true,
            height      :  300,
            width       : 500,
            items       : [{xtype:'submitbutton1',id:'submitbutton'}]
        });
    }
win1.show();
```

when i run this it throws error "b[d.xtype || e] is not a constructor"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an instance of a class for registering xtype. You have to use the classname for it. Ext doesn't keep track of the instances you are creating, but just register the custom component class - so that you can just use this way:

```
var button = new MyApp.SubmitButton({
         id : 'submitbutton'
    });
```

OR,

```
{
     xtype : 'submitbutton',
     id:'submitbutton'
}
```

Both are same. Check Saki's [this article](http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/xtype-defined/) for more information.